Blender 4.2 does not recognize my GPU
I have blender 4.2 running on Linux (Magiea 9) with a Nvidia RTX 4070 (which according to Nvidia has plenty of CUDA power and meets blender requirements) I am added to the render and video grooups on the system
In the preferences it says that I do not have a GPU that not have compute capability above 3
I have reinstalled Blender
I have rebooted a number of times
I have the right Nvidia driver
System-info shows:
`GPU:
renderer:   'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 SUPER/PCIe/SSE2'
vendor:     'NVIDIA Corporation'
version:    '4.6.0 NVIDIA 550.100'
device type:    'NVIDIA'
backend type:   'OPENGL'
Implementation Dependent GPU Limits:
Maximum Batch Vertices: 1048576
Maximum Batch Indices:  1048576
GLSL:
Maximum Varying Floats: 124
Maximum Vertex Attributes:  16
Maximum Vertex Uniform Components:  4096
Maximum Fragment Uniform Components:    4096
Maximum Vertex Image Units: 32
Maximum Fragment Image Units:   32
Maximum Pipeline Image Units:   192
Maximum Image Units:    8
Cycles:
CPU device capabilities: SSE42 AVX2`
I am at a loss for what to do next. Any help would be appreciated

We can't really help with hardware problems as they are off-topic for this Q&A site, however the first thing to do is try updating your graphics drivers in case they aren't actually the latest versions. If that doesn't work see this: Best place to put bug reports?.

Check suggestions on this page https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Setup_the_graphical_server#Nvidia_proprietary_drivers

Thanks. The drivers are the latest according to the Mageia site.

looks like this was the solution, right? https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/127624 - "I needed to add some CUDA libraries that were not automatically installed by my distro."

Yes that was the solution. I would have thought that choosing the appropriate driver would automatically install all that was necessary to use all of the power of the graphics card, but apparently not. Lesson llearned
